# Pivot Table sorting - category instead of "Values"

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Below is the extract of a table i want to sort

[image: Table]

I'd like to create two Pivot Table in two separate sheets so that I only have the start and end Dates corresponding to only one of the two categories, i.e AC156 or AC157

Extract of the result tables

[image]

Since the source list keeps getting updated, I'd really like to do this using Pivot Tables so that I can keep refreshing it.

It seems simple enough but I'm admittedly quite new to Pivot Tables. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your expected outcome? If you cannot do it in pivot table, do a mock table in excel and let us know what should the outcome looks like? I think there should be no issue for you to create two pivot table using the same data source, and no issue for you to filter the category and then sort the dates.

Comment: I just edited my question, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: You can do this using Power Query and *Data >> Get & Transform Data >> From Table/Range*

Answer (score 1):

1. Highlight your data table;
2. Insert a pivot table;
3. Put all three columns into **Rows** field;
4. Right click somewhere within the pivot table, go to `PivotTable Options`, go to `Display`, select **Classic PivotTable layout (enables dragging of fields in the grid)**;
5. If your pivot table has grouped the dates by month, un-check `Months2` in the data fields but leave `Months` if you want to sort by `Start` date;
6. If you pivot table has shown the subtotal for start date, right click the subtotal row and deselect `Subtotal 'Start'`.

You can make a copy of the pivot table, filter the `Cat`, sort the `Months` and then `Start`, then you should have:

[image: Solution]

[image: Fields Setting]